# No data sent to the onSubmit callback when programmatically filling my Redux-Form?

Tags: redux-form

I was using `redux-form` 6.0.0-rc.3 and just upgraded to 6.0.1. A lot change there !

Here's my problem:
I'm trying to programmatically change my sign up form and submit it for some kind of test but I can't manage to get the new values passed to my `onSubmit` callback.

I have something like that:

```
const signUpForm = findRenderedComponentWithType(app, SignUpForm)
signUpForm.props.change('username', 'Joe')
signUpForm.props.change('password', 'isVeryAngryBecauseHeCantSignUp')
Simulate.submit(signUpForm.refs.submitButton)
```

but my `onSubmit` function is called but receives an empty object as the first parameter, the data.

After some investigations, I see that the sign up form state doesn't have any trace of the new values:

```
state {
  registeredFields: [
    { name: 'username', type: 'Field' },
    { name: 'password', type: 'Field' }
  ],
  fields: { username: { touched: true }, password: { touched: true } },
  anyTouched: true,
  submitting: true
}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ? That would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1247

Basically, the `signUpForm.props.change` returns a redux action. It is not bound to the store `dispatch` as written in the doc.

`store.dispatch(signUpForm.props.change)` works around the problem for now.